# If parent element has certain class, fade in child element

Tags: jquery

I'm having some trouble with this.

Basically I want to first check if a certain element has a particular class (In this case `.active`) and, if it does, I want to use jQuery's `fadeIn` on the `.active` elements children.

This is what I'm using currently but it doesn't seem to work;

```
if ( $('.slides li').hasClass('active') ){
    $('.slides li .content').delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$('.slides li.active .content').delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
```

in your case any of the `li` has the class active all .content element within the `slides` are shown

Comment: This worked for the first slide in my slider, but none of the other slides `.content` divs showed up once their parent had the `.active` class applied

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
$('.slides li').each(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
      }
});
```